# Is trunk needed in multiversion projects

Tags: svn, version-control, project-management

I work in a project with one released version in maintenance and two or more versions in development simultaneously.

Here is where the doubts about the need of trunk arises.

I've read the SVN Book in The Read Bean and others (Pragmatic Version Control with Subversion) and all of then suggest using a trunk-centric mode of development. I don't know if in my case this is applicable and if exist other projects with multiversion release cycle that use other schemas successfully.

Why is the trunk-centric mode the recommended?
Is there any problem with the version branches going more and more far of the trunk?
I this schema the integrations with trunk have any sense?

```
                                          /-----gamma-----/(3)---------->
                                         /               /
               /----beta---/(1)---/(2)--/---beta--------/--\
              /           /      /                          \
     /------------alpha--/------/---\                        \
    /                                \                        \
------------trunk--------------------(a)----------------------(b)------------------>
```

Edit:

When I say two or more development versions I mean versions of the software with incremental level of functionality. In the *graphic* above:

- alpha: functionality A.
- beta: functionality A + B.
- gamma: functionality A + B + C.

Meaning that *all* the functionality of a branch is included in later branches (through sync merges). The branches differ in stability level (*older* branches are more stable) and in functionality (*young* branches have new functionality).

Edit 2, after TridenT answer:

The development of the stable version is done in a trunk's branch and then merged back to trunk when is stable, so the trunk contains all the stable changes and in the end the more stable version of the software.

I'm asking this question now because I'm rethinking the branching strategy of the whole project.

Comment: Can you explain how this can be possible:" two or more versions in development simultaneously". Are you realy talking about new versions of the software or about features beeing worked on by several teams?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to take your chart and reorganize it a bit:

```
                                          /-----gamma-----/(3)---------->
                                         /               /
               /----beta---/(1)---/(2)--/---beta--------/--\
              /           /      /                          \
     /------------alpha--/------/---\                        \
    /                                \                        \
------------trunk--------------------(a)----------------------(b)------------------>
```

First, remove `trunk`, since you're not using it. Yes, you're merging back into the trunk, but you never take code out of it. Instead, `beta` comes from `alpha` and `gamma` comes from `beta`. Might as well save yourself all that effort merging back into a code line you never really use:

```
                                          /-----gamma-----/(3)---------->
                                         /               /
               /----beta---/(1)---/(2)--/---beta--------/
              /           /      /                      
     /------------alpha--/------/                    
    /                                      
trunk
```

Now, let's straighten out your chart, so that the main development line is nice and straight:

```
trunk-alpha-------beta-----------------------gamma-------------------------->
            \           /      /       \                /
             \---alpha-/------/         \---beta-------/
```

And, finally flip over everything...

```
             /-alpha-\-----\            /--beta-------\
            /         \     \          /               \
trunk------/--(beta)---\-----\--------/-(gamma)---------\------(gamma)-------->
```

There's your trunk!

I know what you're doing. You're not coding on trunk because trunk is suppose to represent your release. In your original diagram, there are two versions on trunk. Point (a) where you merge branch alpha back to trunk, and Point (b) where you merge branch beta back to trunk. This represents your Release alpha and Release beta.

However, that's what tags are for! You make a tag on a release, and your tag now represents your release. And, it's better because a tag preserves the history of your file.

Let's say you go to your trunk at Point (b) and take a log of a particular file. You see the file at Point (b) and you see another version at Point (a). But, you have no idea how that file was changed between point (a) and point (b). In fact, you don't even know who's release responsible for a particular change.

However, if you did a tag off the branch instead of merging your code back to trunk, you'd see the entire history of that file all the back to the very first version of the file. Subversion's log command (if you don't use the `--stop-on-copy` switch) will take you from the tag down to branch beta and back to trunk.

Ah, you say, but how can I see the differences between release alpha and release beta? In my scheme, I can look at the history of the trunk!

However, if you need to see all the changes between one release and another, you could easily just do a diff between two tags. And, sine they're tags, it's much easier to find the actual release version instead of trying to figure out which version on trunk represents your which release.

So, you do have a trunk, but you just don't call it that.

Comment: We cannot develop directly in the trunk because the release order of the different product versions can change by client request. The moment I have time I'll do a _graphic_ with a possible trunk-centric schema using your suggestions.

Comment: I will try to redesign the branching strategy so the trunk become the real trunk. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The need for a trunk paradigm (or, in the git world, devel) is mostly the need for a point where cutting-edge development (feature branches) and quality control measures (release branches) meet. It serves as a common ground for all active branches, which are mostly defined through their difference to the trunk.

The vast majorities of projects have trunks, and most of the projects that think they have none have one nonetheless, but don't realize it. The trunk is the branch of the project that receives all new features and is not intended to terminate. When you have multiple branches with this property, they are either equal or will drift so far apart from each other that you have two projects. The tree metaphor is really great here - where there are two trunks, there are two trees.

While alternative models often seem fine at the start, people often find out the hard way that more than one permanent active branch is deadly to team communication. The advantage of a trunk is that anyone in the team developing a feature can branch off from trunk, develop, merge into trunk and be happy. With multiple active branches, you will have to merge into multiple branches or suffer a functionality fork with all the bad debugging and user support.
That's the main reason for adopting a trunk scheme. [Vincent Driessen has written a splendid article about this development model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), which applies to SVN as well once you replace the devel branch by the trunk.

It seems that you do actually follow a trunk scheme with your project. Your young branches (gamma in the example) are actually the trunk of the project because they receive new functionality. The older branches (alpha and beta) receive bug fixes, which are later merged into the branch you called trunk. However, since you never fork off again from trunk, but only from gamma, the merges from alpha and beta are unnecessary. Trunk seems to have the least features and the most stability (oldest branch), which is contrary to normal trunk logic.

So, you could represent your project structure by a trunk that follows the uppermost lines in your example (branches from "trunk" into "alpha" into "beta" into "gamma") and multiple release branches ("alpha" and "beta") that merge into trunk regularily *and are intended to terminate*. This way, you have erased one unnecessary branch (labelled "trunk") and have far easier merge schemes.

This usage contrasts with your requirement for "two or more versions in development simultaneously", but looking at your schema, I think that only a single version receives new features. If I thought wrong, please clarify this point.

Comment: We work in a way similar to te Vincent Driessen article you are linking: we have a production version branch where the more urgent changes are done, stabiliced and released, then this changes are merged to trunk.

At the same time there are other trunk's branches with different level of functionality (future production versions) that in the future will became the production version branch. This branches are updated with trunk to gain the stable funcionality.

Answer (score 0):

It reminds me of the **stable - testing - unstable** versioning from **Debian**.
Your model is **perfectly valid**, as long as it represents the way you work.

Trunk-centric has one benefit: no matter how many branches you have, the trunk is normally the latest stable version in current development.

Comment: "the trunk is normaly the latest stable version in current development": This sentence might be a bit confusing for people who think of versions in terms of releases and of stability in term of non-development. I'd argue that trunk is the most feature-rich branch that is still expected to compile and be integrated. You probably meant just that, but wanted to be sure.

Comment: @thiton: Yes, you explained it nicely, better than me ;) Thx for your comment.

Comment: The thing is that in our project the concept of trunk is just that: the more stable version of the software. The development of the stable version is done in a trunk's branch and then merged back to trunk when is stable, so the trunk contains all the stable changes and in the end the more stable version of the software.